# Graphene-Django: Concepts of Connections, Edges, and Nodes

Tags: django, graphene-python

I just started experimenting with graphene-django/GraphQL and am pretty confused about the relay library that has been brought in for graphene-django. After running through the cookbook example (implementing it with my own models) and running a test query, upon POST the query gets transformed to a strangely nested object with edges and nodes. What are these and what are they doing?

```
{
  companies {
    edges {
      node {
       id
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm also new to Relay. This is a standard setup.  Check out this explanation https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm

Comment: The reason this question came up was we wanted to use graphene-djano within our app without the relay dependency for filtering. I was able to find a technique to add filtering without using relay here [link](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/215)

Comment: I see what you mean.  As noted in your link, the advantage of sticking with relay conventions is that graphene gives you a pre-built setup for paging.  A GraphQL  query with  "pageInfo {
                hasNextPage
                hasPreviousPage
                startCursor
                endCursor
              }" works automatically.

Comment: We did discuss that as a pro, however, with the app we are building we decided it we'd rather have a cleaner query strings and query results over pagination. Worst case scenario, we'll attempt to roll our own pagination using filtering offsets and subsets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Node

It may be worth mentioning that `Node` is part of the [Facebook Relay specs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-object-identification.html) (not GraphQL specs). However, most framework (Graphene included) implement this spec due to the close association between Relay and GraphQL.

Essentially `Node` is an interface that implements just an `ID` field, which is meant to be an globally unique identifier for an object. `ID`s are designed to be opaque (typical convention is to `base64('type:id')`), applications should not attempt to rely on this implementation detail.

`Node` is exposed as part of the root Query, where applications can query for entities with known `ID` in a convenient way, e.g. refetching, fetching fields that have not been fetched.

```
{
  node(id: ID!) {
    ... on User {
      id
      userId
      name 
    }
    ... on Company {
      id
      companyId
      owner: {
        userId
        name
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

This provides the convenience of **not** having to define query point for every model you expose (e.g. `message(messageId)` or `user(userId)`). This also allows you to query for the object without transversing through an object path, example

```
{
  user {
    friends {
      pages {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}

// vs

{
  node(id) {
    ... on Page {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

## Connection

Like `Node`, `Connection` is also part of the [Relay specs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-connections.html) that made its way to mainstream adoption.

At first glance, the concept of `edges` seems superfluous but it does solve some tricky use case. Consider the need to expose a many-to-many relationship like 'friends', typically implemented in a database with a join table.

```
+---------+         +------------+
| users   |         | friends    |
+---------+         +------------+
| user_id | <------ | left_id    |
| ....    |    \--- | right_id   |
+---------+         | created_at |
                    +------------+
```

It is now easy to display "Friends since [date here]" by exposing `friends.created_at` in the edge object.

```
{
  user {
    friends {
      edges {
        created_at  <---
        user {
          id
          userId
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`edges` essentially defines the relationship between `nodes`.

Answer (score 0):

M2M relationship between `Atable` and `Btable` must to be implemented by third link (join) table `ABLink`, which must have at least two foreign keys:

```
+------+------+------------+--------+  
| A_id | B_id | Created_at | Status |  
+------+------+------------+--------+
```

Is it right to say for m2m that `edge` represent such link (join) table in database? 
So then query for that would be:

```
{
  Atable {
    ABLink {
      edges {
        Created_at
        Status
        Btable {
          Btable_id
          Btable_column_1
          Btable_column_2
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```